# borda redonda no EditText Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação mobile utilizando o Android studio 2.2.2, e queria deixar minha aplicação com esse visual.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas não estou conseguindo colocar a borda e a linha encima do editText

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.tulio.exercicio2.MainActivity">



<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:hint="De"
    android:textColor="#5e605f"
     />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Para"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textColor="#5e605f"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editView3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Assunto"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textColor="#5e605f"
     />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editView4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Mensagem"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textColor="#5e605f"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />

   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar `xml-drawables` para chegar neste resultado, mas também existem uma outra alternativa se caso você queira, por exemplo, aplicar sombras na sua view ao invés de deixar ela com um visual mais chapado.

**XML Drawables**

Você pode aprender um pouco mais sobre esses arquivos na seção [recursos desenháveis](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html?hl=pt-br) da documentação do Android.

Neste caso, você utilizaria a tag `selector` para criar uma `shape`. Dentro desta shape, você utilizará as tags `solid` para criar um background **sólido**, `corners` para arredondar a drawable, se caso você queira, e `stroke` para adicionar a borda.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#fff"/> <!-- cor do sólido -->
            <corners android:radius="12dp"/> <!-- valor do arredondamento das bordas -->
            <stroke android:color="#eee" android:width="2dp"/> <!-- cor da borda e tamanho dela -->
            <padding android:bottom="8dp" android:left="8dp" android:right="8dp" android:top="8dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Pronto, você criou o seu background e agora poderá utilizar ele como o **background** da sua View. No código acima, você pode estar estranhando a tag `padding`, mas ela é basicamente para evitar que o background fique muito colado com a `EditText`.

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/my_bg"/>
```

Comment: o que seria  <shape android:shape="rectangle"> ?

Comment: O atributo `shape="rectangle"` significa de que forma a sua view irá se comportar, neste caso, como um retângulo (será criado um retângulo no preview). As opções disponíveis para este atributo são: rectangle, oval, line, ring, @FelipePatrocinio

Answer (score 3):

Em primeiro momento, há 3 opções de fazer isso:

1. Criar um *background* customizado e definir no XML do `EditText`;
2. Criar um *background* customizado e definir programaticamente no `EditText`;
3. Criar um *background* programaticamente e definir programaticamente no `EditText`;

Inicialmente você precisa conhecer essas 3 propriedades abaixo:

- `<solid>`: Define uma cor solida para o *background*
- `<corners>`: define a configurações dos cantos, no qual pode ser definido em raios.
- `<stroke>`: define a configurações das bordas que abaixo foi definido uma cor cinza `@android:color/darker_gray` e a largura de `1dp`;

Então basta criar um arquiv o dentro `res/drawable/` como como por exemplo `border_rounded.xml`. Veja:

#### Opção 1:

Definir no XML do `EditText`:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/border_rounded"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    />
```

#### Opção 2:

Definir programaticamente no `EditText`:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    et.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.border_rounded));
} else {
    et.setBackgroundDrawable( ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.border_rounded) );
}
```

#### Opção 3:

Criar um *background* programaticamente e defini-lo programaticamente no `EditText`.

Primeiro é necessário criar um [`GradientDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html) com as propriedades primordiais para definição das bordas redondas do `EditText`. Veja:

```
public GradientDrawable setBorderRounded(){
    GradientDrawable shape =  new GradientDrawable();
    shape.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    shape.setCornerRadius(10);
    shape.setStroke(2, Color.GRAY);
    return shape;
}
```

Logo depois, basta definir como *background* do `EditText`. Veja:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    et.setBackground(setBorderRounded());
else
    et.setBackgroundDrawable(setBorderRounded());
```

Veja mais detalhes na documentação sobre [recursos desenháveis](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html?hl=pt-br).